# 2 Azure VM Servers from the same region cannot communicate with each other

Tags: virtual-machines, azure-networking, azure-vm

I have 2 Azure VM Windows Datacenter 2019 OS, that are in the same Region and are connected via VNET Peering but still cannot see or access each other, I tried turning off the Firewall from both VMs but to no avail, I'm at my wit's end, any other troubleshooting recommendations anyone could suggest or settings that I could check.

my main goal is to connect to SQL between the 2 VMs, even though they are connected via VNet Peering successfully they cannot Ping each others IP

[image]

Comment: Tell us exactly how you're trying to have them "see and access" each other and tell us exactly what happens when you try.